# Need help modifying JavaScript-based accordion box on web-page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

Here is the [website](http://black-eyedsuzie.com/) for view.

First of all, I am rather new at JavaScript, so this is why I am deferring to the community here.

I have a simple accordion box in the central column on the first page of the website. It works very well, but I want the "2014 Shows" portion of the accordion to be open upon page-load. Otherwise the headers look empty, initially, until clicked on. That will not do!

*NOTE: I do plan to add little up/down arrows beside each header of the accordion to make it a bit more apparent that it is, in fact, an accordion.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="accordionButton">
    <h1>2014 Shows</h1>
</div>
<div class="accordionContent">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
</div>
<div class="accordionButton">
    <h1>2013 Shows</h1>
</div>
<div class="accordionContent">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

The corresponding CSS:

```
.accordionButton {  
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordionContent { 
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}
```

And the corresponding script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function() {
    //MAKE THE ACCORDION CLOSE ON THE SECOND CLICK
        if ($('div.accordionContent').hasClass('openDiv')) {
            $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().removeClass('openDiv');
        }
        else {
            $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            $(this).next().addClass('openDiv');
        }
    });
    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You this code collapsing all the divs:

```
$("div.accordionContent").hide();
```

Change the selector to hide all except the first one:

```
$("div.accordionContent").slice(1).hide();
```

See [CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) and [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for further help.

Comment: This makes sense, but it doesn't work. Would I need to specify which is the first-child, before it would work? That might be a dumb question... Like I said, java is new to me.

Comment: @mateikav I've corrected it to use `.slice` instead. It didn't work, because the div isn't the first child, it has the header before it.

Comment: You should refactor this code to remove explicitly calling `div` because that's an unnecessary call within the Sizzle DOM object parser. (e.g. `$('.accordionContent')`

Comment: You can also call `$('.accordionContent').first()` to get the first in that array series.

Comment: @lxe I played with `.slice` for a while but that doesn't work either. Will look at the other solutions.

Comment: Maybe the issue lies elsewhere? Removing `$("div.accordionContent").hide();` yields no changes.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS that declared display: none; to start things off made something of a seperation of tasks.  If we have JavaScript and are going to adjust the visibility with that, then we should do it all with the JS.  If there's no JavaScript, then the user isn't missing any information.

the style, small change:

```
    .accordionButton {  
        width: 320px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .accordionContent { 
        width: 320px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Otherwise, I changed your html for your divs to declare which we want to be visible within the html so it's easier to maintain and lay out.

html in the body:

```
<div class="accordionButton">
        <h1>2014 Shows</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="accordionContent openDiv">
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="accordionButton">
        <h1>2013 Shows</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="accordionContent closedDiv">
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
```

And then I tightened up the JavaScript and, as there are only two elements, clicking either "button" will show one and hide the other.  But it should be easier now to alternate that behavior to whatever you like.

and the script:

```
    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION
    $('.accordionButton').click(function() {
        //MAKE THE ACCORDION CLOSE ON THE SECOND CLICK
        $('.accordionContent.openDiv').slideUp('normal', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('openDiv').addClass('closedDiv');
        });
        $('.accordionContent.closedDiv').slideDown('normal', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('closedDiv').addClass('openDiv');
        });
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD
    $(".accordionContent.closedDiv").eq(0).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive reply. I'm trying out your idea and now the accordion is all open on load and stays stuck that way.

Comment: Check the console log, it sounds like there's a JavaScript error somewhere that's breaking the script

Comment: I came up with another solution with some help. Will post it. I think it was a bit easier than my initial style.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was more elegant than my initial idea. It involved changing the whole method.

Html:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h1 class="accordion-toggle">2014 Shows<img style="vertical-align:middle; padding-left:5px;" src="media/down_accordion.gif" width="10px" height="5px" /></h1>
        <div class="accordion-content default">
            <p>AUG 1-3 Fire &amp; Water Music Festival<br />Lac Du Bonnet, MB | Time TBA</p>
            <p>MAR 19 black-eyed SUZIE Studio w/ West My Friend<br />Minitonas, MB | 7:00PM</p>
            <p>JAN 1 New Year's House Concert<br />Gilbert Plains, MB | 8:00PM</p>
        </div>
    <h1 class="accordion-toggle">2013 Shows<img style="vertical-align:middle; padding-left:5px;" src="media/down_accordion.gif" width="10px" height="5px" /></h1>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-content.default {
    display: block;
}
```

Java:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

        });
    });
</script>
```

It appears to work well! Thanks all for the input. Your ideas got me researching some new things. Java is still a bit foreign to me.